# Is it possible to access text message information through iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing an application where in i want to alert the user if he receives a message from a contact.
I have been struggling for the same yet haven't found any solution to this. 
I also wanted to know if the sdk 3.0 allows access to the call history..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no access to SMS messages from the application sandbox, and there is no access to call logs from the application sandbox. You can [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com) a feature request with Apple, but I doubt you will see changes to this any time soon. You will not be able to provide any functionality in your app that depends on this information.

Answer (score 2):

Similar question here regarding call history:

[Reading call history in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144888/reading-call-history-in-iphone-os)

Short answer is, not possible.  I do not believe this has changed in 3.0.