# How to programmatically get a list of all iPhone calls and messages?

Tags: iphone

Is it even possible, without jailbreak?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading call history in iPhone OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144888/reading-call-history-in-iphone-os)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't access the call history and Messages.  We can access address book,photos/pictures, user location, but not call logs and messages.

Hopefully this will be available in future versions

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible see also [Reading call history in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144888/reading-call-history-in-iphone-os)