# Access call history in iphone.?

Tags: iphone, calllog, core-telephony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading call history in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144888/reading-call-history-in-iphone-os)

Hi my new requirement is to access calllog (incoming/outgoing/missed calls) from iphone. Is there any framework or API for accessing that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as non-jailbroken phones it is **not possible** i.e. no support of official sdk.

Answer (score 2):

lock at

1. [iPhone call log / history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history)
2. [iphone “unable to open database file” for call_history.db in xcode app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498291/iphone-unable-to-open-database-file-for-call-history-db-in-xcode-app)
3. [Reading call history in iPhone OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144888/reading-call-history-in-iphone-os)